# How to specify a nil date expression using Core Data Model Editor (Xcode 4.3.2)?

Tags: xcode, core-data

I am trying to create a Fetch Request, **not in code**, but by using the Core Data Model Editor, to get all Book objects that have no value for the date attribute.

I tried various ways to specify this. One example as...

[image: 'bookDate == nil' predicate - what i need]

...however, when I leave and return back to the data model editor, Xcode has changed it to this, where the date is today's date...

[image: 'bookDate is today's date' predicate - not what i need]

If this is just a limitation of the model editor, and doing it in code is the only way, then so be it. I'm just trying to be consistent since all of my other fetch requests have been done in the model editor, and have not been a problem to define.

Answer (score 0):

Aaah, this is almost a philosophical issue. `nil` is simply not a valid date, so it should not be in the predicate. There is a simple workaround, though:

Initialize your date to some extreme value, and check for that value (or if the date is beyond that value).

---

I also noticed that perhaps in the editor it is just a display thing. If you toggle the switch in the upper right corner (Editor/Expression view I guess) you will see that the query has not changed, even if in one view today's date is displayed.

[image: switch toggle]

Therefore it might just work anyway. In this case it is just a display bug.

Comment: The underlying persistence store is SQLite, which allows for "nullable" values, e.g., "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE bookDate IS NULL". And since Core Data Model Editor attributes can be declared as "Optional", it would make sense that optional attributes with no value would be stored with value of NULL. So it is sounding more and more like a limitation of Xcode/Model Editor that needs to be worked around my using a magic value that means "no value" instead of using  NULL as so many other platforms do.

Comment: Well, there is the philosophical misunderstanding. Core Data is not "an SQL database" but an object graph. So null values simply do not make sense in a predicate.

Comment: @Mundi Huh? Sure, nil isn't a date, but it's a valid attribute value. Optional attributes don't need to have values.

Comment: What noa said. Plus, I never said Core Data "is a SQL database". I said **the underlying persistence store in the default implementation (which is what I'm using) is SQLite**. Inserts to my Books model show the date columns with null values (using SQLite Manager plugin for Firefox). And I have no problem specifying a [NSNull null] value in the predicate **in code**. I just wanted to know how to do it properly using Model Editor. So it's either not supported, or just not documented, even though the Editor UI options, i.e., **Optional attributes** suggest otherwise.

Comment: Point well taken. Does the predicate work even if it is not displayed correctly?